# How can I parse part of a URL from an variable?

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to write a playbook that will go and download the version of ombi I supply on the command line as a variable, then parse part of it so I can rename the file and keep a local copy of it. Then gunzip then untar then stop the service overwrite the existing app, then restart the service.

I've written several other playbooks but parsing this part out has me stumped.

So if say this was the URL
https://github.com/Ombi-app/Ombi/releases/download/v4.32.0/linux-x64.tar.gz

I want to extract the 4.32.0 out of that url.  So my playbook run line might be something like:

```
ansible-playbook updateombi.yml --extra-vars "ombi_release=https://github.com/Ombi-app/Ombi/releases/download/v4.32.0/linux-x64.tar.gz"
```

I'm assuming I would declare a var like:

```yaml
ombi_version: "{{ ombi_release | urlsplit('path') }}"
```

but the urlsplit is what's got me stumped.  Anyone able to throw me a bone?

Comment: Hi wharris623 welcome to SO. Stumped in what way? That does what it says on the tin and extracts the `path` from that URL, but your variable is named `ombi_version` so I presume you want the `v4.32.0` part? If that's the case, using urlsplit will never get that done, you'll want [`| regex_search`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions)

Comment: The other way could be `"{{ (ombi_release |split('/'))[-2]   }}"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I'm trying to write a playbook that will go and download the version of Ombi I supply on the command line as a variable ...*

To do so you could simply provide the version number only

```bash
ansible-playbook updateombi.yml --extra-vars "ombi_release=4.32.0"
```

and construct the URL and filename afterwards within your playbook

```yaml
url: "https://github.com/Ombi-app/Ombi/releases/download/v{{ ombi_release }}/linux-x64.tar.gz"
dest: /tmp/linux-x64-v{{ ombi_release }}.tar.gz
```

since they don't have a variable part except the version number. By doing this there would be no need for

> *... then parse part of it so I can rename the file ...*

Comment: U880D - That's really elegant!  I like the way you think!  Thanks so much for the assist!

Comment: I can't upvote yet, I don't have a reputation of 15 but I did the green tick!

Comment: @U880D Just wanted to let you know, I got it working thanks to your help!    Not sure if I could post the code in the comment or not, but still huge thanks!